# Вывести максимальное значение массива в заданном отрезке начинающегося с числа i и имеющего длину n

Tags: php, php7

Вот таким образом у меня выводит 4 элемента в диапазоне в "4 значения". То есть цикл Выводит 19,20,52,53. Не могу понять как вывести максимальное число в этом диапазоне? В данном случае будет 53 но важно чтоб где бы я не написал максимальное число оно у меня высветиться на экран. 
В диапазоне этих 4 значений! Помогите Пожалуйста. Обьясните на словах как это можно сделать.

```
$arr=[ 42, 2, 19, 20, 52, 53, 7, 8, 8, 0,];

$n=4;
for($i=2;$i<=$n+1;$i++){
  echo $arr[$i];
}
```

Comment: Вам нужна еще одна переменная `$b`, которой вы будете присваивать значение, руководствуясь логикой - "Если `$b`  меньше чем `$arr[$i]`, то `$b=$arr[$i]`

Comment: что то все тоже самое получаеться

Comment: все как вы сказали написал опять выводить перечень значений которые были(

Comment: А где объявлена $b? Обрати на это внимание.

Comment: Спасибо большое)Первый вариант который вы предлогали я не раз пробовал но ни как не понимал что нужно было Объявить переменную за циклом for!

Comment: Спасибо еще раз)Вокруг да около ходил. Теперь буду знать!

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял

```
<? 
   $arr = array( 42, 2, 19, 20, 52, 53, 7, 8, 8, 0); 

   // Разбиваем массив на куски по 4 
   $arr = array_chunk($arr, 4); 

   // Сюда собираем самое большое из каждого сегмента 
   $result = array(); 

   foreach($arr as &$val){ 
      // $val сегмент 
      rsort($val); // сортируем DESC 
      $result[] = $val[0]; // Первый всегда больщий 
   };

   echo '<pre>'; 
   print_r($arr); 
   echo '</pre>';

   echo '<pre>'; 
   print_r($result); 
   echo '</pre>'; 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

находите позицию этого числа `i` в массиве. Отрезаете кусок в 4 элемента, находите максимум.

```
 $i = 2;
 $n = 4;

 $idx = array_search($i, $arr);
 if($idx !== false){
      $slice = array_slice($arr, $idx, $n);
      $result = max($slice);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вам обязательно нужно использовать цикл то:

```
$arr = [42, 2, 64, 20, 52, 53, 7, 8, 8, 0,];
$i = 2;
$n = 4;

$max = 0;
for ($j = $i; $j <= $n + 1; $j++) {
    if ($arr[$j] > $max) {
        $max = $arr[$j];
    }
}
echo $max;
```

Ну а в целом можно одно строчкой:

```
echo max(array_slice($arr, $i, $n));
```

Comment: судя по заголовку, 2 это не индекс, а значение

Comment: А судя по описанию и предложенному решению в вопросе - это именно индекс.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$input = [ 42, 2, 19, 20, 52, 53, 7, 8, 8, 0,];
$offset = 2;
$count = 4;

$max = array_reduce(
    array_splice($input, $offset, $count),
    function ($carry, $item) {
        return $carry === null? $item: max($carry, $item);
    }
);
```

Срез ([array_splice](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-slice.php)) исходного массива приводим к одному значению ([array_reduce](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-reduce.php)), используя анонимную функцию для нахождения максимального значения.

Полученный результат - масимальное значение из всех значени элементов среза.

Answer (score 0):

$arr=[ 5, 1, 70, 900, 300, 0, -500, -300, -100, 1,];
$n=2;

$max=0;

$left=5;

$right= 0;

$right= $n + $left;

for ($i=$left;$i

if ($max< $arr[$i] || $max ==0)

$max=$arr[$i];

}
echо $max;

Ребят подскажите пожалуйста в чем проблема почему у меня не выводит максимальное число '0'  в данном случае ?а выводит -500? В диапазоне двух значений!Прошу объясните на словах без кода.Заранее спасибо за подсказку!